# custom agenda view in org mode grouping per month

Tags: org-agenda, org-super-agenda

Using org mode agenda I've been able to customize a view to have all tasks no matter if finished or not this way:

```
 (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("w" "Whole Agenda no matter status"
         ((todo "TODO|IN-PROGRESS|DONE|CANCELLED"))) 
        ))
```

I need a step more: group by month showing a header, but I'm stuck. I don´t know how to group tasks by month in my custom view (preferably month of DONE date if exists, if not, then date of insertion).

something like this:

```
January
-------------
Project A:DONE task1  2019-01-01
Project A:CANCELLED task2  2019-01-02
Project B:DONE task3 2019-01-03
February
--------------
Project A:TODO task4 2019-02-01
Project B:TODO task5 2019-02-04
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `org-super-agenda` https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda
It groups agenda view lines in many possible ways.

When installed, a hook and interactive function (<kbd>M-x eval-buffer</kbd> in scratch, or saved in *.emacs*):

```el
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook #'org-super-agenda-mode)

(defun my-monthly-agenda ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-custom-commands
         '(("w" "Whole Agenda no matter status"
            ((todo "TODO|IN-PROGRESS|DONE|CANCELLED")))))

        (org-super-agenda-groups
         '((:auto-map
            (lambda (item)
              (let ((ts (assoc "TIMESTAMP" (org-entry-properties))))
                (if ts
                    (let* ((date-parts (org-parse-time-string (cdr ts)))
                           (month (nth 4 date-parts)) (year (nth 5 date-parts)))
                      (format-time-string "%B %Y" (encode-time 1 1 1 1 month year)))
                  ;; else
                  "W/o timestamp")))))))
    (org-agenda nil "w")))
```

<kbd>M-x my-monthly-agenda</kbd>

### Result:

```
Global list of TODO items of type: TODO|IN-PROGRESS|DONE|CANCELLED

 January 2019
  test:       TODO Prepare slides               :work:boss:notes::action:

 November 2006
  test:       TODO Write letter to Sam Fortune

 W/o timestamp
  test:       DONE Head A
  test:       TODO Prepare slides 2             :work:boss:notes::action:
```

Comment: but an issue arised. Order is not monthly order but alphabeticall, i mean, groups are W/o timestamp,, december 2006, January 2006,november 2006

Comment: Looks like this not not fetch `IN-PROGRESS` if lines started with `* IN-PROGRESS ...`

Comment: This only shows `W/o timestamp` section